# How to solve: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==4.1.1.26

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, opencv

```
I am trying to install requirements.txt below from github in anaconda virtual environment.

requirements.txt: opencv-python==4.1.1.26  
                  lxml  
                  tqdm
                  tensorflow==2.3.0  
                  absl-py  
                  easydict  
                  matplotlib  
                  pillo

After using the command : `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`(`pip install -r requirements.txt`) 

The error came out :
```

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==4.1.1.26 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.14.53, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.2.54, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==4.1.1.26

```
How can I solve this?

python  3.7.2  
pip     22.2.2  
Ubuntu  16.04  
conda   4.5.12
```

Comment: the alternative is try download and install it manually
https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/4.1.1.26/#files

Comment: Which command should i use then. Thanks.

Comment: after you downloaded the file, just run this command pip install name_package

Comment: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-cpu-aws 2.10.0rc3 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, which is not installed.
tensorflow-cpu-aws 2.10.0rc3 requires six>=1.12.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.10.0 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, which is not installed.
keras-preprocessing 1.1.2 requires six>=1.9.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 2.10.0 requires setuptools>=41.0.0, but you have setuptools 40.4.3 which is incompatible.

Comment: I got this with successfully installed, do the errors make big deal?

Comment: try a newer version. there's no reason to request a very specific very old version.

Comment: I afraid that use a new version instead of the one in requirements.txt will make something wrong.

Comment: You can try installing each package manually by specifying the version details as `!pip install tensorflow==2.3`, `!pip install opencv-python==4.1.1.26`, `!pip install matplotlib`. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.